# Can this condition be shortened ? (if/else condition)

Tags: php

I have a condition:

```
    if($about AND $desc) 
    {
        if($about > $desc) {
            $description = $about;
        }
        else {
            $description = $desc;
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        if($about AND !$desc) {
            $description = $about;
        }
        elseif (!$about AND $desc) {
            $description = $desc;
        }
        else { 
            $description = 'No description';
        }
    }
```

For me it seems too big. I think it can be somehow shortened, but have no idea how.. Any suggestions ?

Comment: This question would be better suited on http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Thanks James, I didn't knew about that one.

Comment: Shortening is not the goal. Readability is the goal.

Comment: Shortening makes it more readable sometimes. Check the original code vs. [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27443743/4265352) below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refining the answer provided by @h2ooooooo you can simplify it even more by replacing `($about > $desc ? $about : $desc)` with `max($about, $desc)` to get this:

```
$description = ($about || $desc) ? max($about, $desc) : 'No description';
```

and because `max()` can compare about anything you can make it even simpler, like this:

```
$decription = max($about, $desc) ?: 'No description';
```

Comment: Half of the credit goes to @h2ooooooo, he answered faster than me. Just clicked +1 on his solution. :-)

Answer (score 6):

Check if `$about` OR `$desc` is truthy, and use a ternary operator from there:

```
if ($about || $desc) {
    $description = ($about > $desc ? $about : $desc);
} else {
    $description = 'No description';
}
```

If you really wish to shorten it even more (and **limit readability**, which I do not suggest), you can turn the entire thing into ternary:

```
$description = (($about || $desc) ? ($about > $desc ? $about : $desc) : 'No description');
```

Comment: Exactly the answer I was about to post. +1 added.

Answer (score 1):

or make a function and use return

```
function getDescription($about, $desc) {

  if (!$about && !$desc)
        return 'No description';

  if ($about > $desc)
        return $about;

  return $desc;
}
```

or

```
$description = function($about, $desc) {

  if (!$about && !$desc)
        return 'No description';

  if ($about > $desc)
        return $about;

  return $desc;
};
```